# Change in Values of Dropdown , based on other dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstl

I have two dropdowns

**Dropdown 1**

```
<form:select path="StartTimings" id="startTime" onchange="javascript:changeTiming()">
   <form:option value="9:00 AM">9:00 AM</form:option>
   <form:option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</form:option>
   <form:option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</form:option>
   <form:option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</form:option>
   <form:option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</form:option>
   <form:option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</form:option>
   <form:option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</form:option>
</form:select>
```

**Dropdown 2**

```
<form:select path="EndTimings" id="endTime">
   <form:option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</form:option>
   <form:option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</form:option>
   <form:option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</form:option>
   <form:option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</form:option>
   <form:option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</form:option>
   <form:option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</form:option>
   <form:option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</form:option>
</form:select>
```

**Snippet of javascript function**

```
function changeTiming() {    
    var select1 = document.getElementById("startTime");

    if (select1.value == "10:00 AM") {
      document.getElementById("endTime").selectedIndex = 1;
    } else if (select1.value == "11:00 AM") {
      document.getElementById("endTime").selectedIndex = 2;
    } else if (select1.value == "12:00 PM") {
      document.getElementById("endTime").selectedIndex = 3;
    }
```

I need some help in writing/modifying above javascript function in Which the value(time) in **DropDown 2** should always be greater than the value selected in **DropDown 1**. i.e If a user selects 11 AM from DropDown 1, the DropDown 2 must **ONLY** contain all the values greater than 11AM i.e 12PM, 1PM, 2PM, 3PM, 4PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/VSuBD/)

```
window.onload=function() {
  var start = document.getElementById("startTime");
  var end   = document.getElementById("endTime");
  start.onchange=function() {
    end.options.length=0;
    for (var i=this.selectedIndex+1;i<this.options.length;i++) {
      end.options[end.options.length]=new Option(this.options[i].text,this.options[i].value);
    }
    end.options[end.options.length]=new Option("4:00 PM","4:00 PM");
  }
  start.onchange();
}
```

Comment: Hello mplungjan, Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

This can be really simple.

Store 1 set of your times in an array.

Loop through them to load the start time.

Your onChange event should then get the selectedIndex of the startTime selected and loop through the times array from that number to load the endtime.

Good luck with your code.

Comment: I appreciate your suggested solution.
Thanks :)